# What is the best way to have polymorphic implementations on a generic in go (1.18)?

Tags: go, generics

I want to create a Vector type that is generic over its internal data but may have differ in how the methods are implemented given the input type.

```
type SupportedType interface {
         ~int64 | ~uint64 |  ~float64 | string | bool | time.Time
}

type Vec[T SupportedType] struct {
    data []T
}
```

and I want to add a varying implementations on a function depending on the type. For example:

```
func (vec Vec[T]) Sort() {
    ...
}
```

In most of the generic types `<` will work just fine. However, if `T -> time.Time` I want to use the `Before` method and if `T --> bool` then I want all the false values to go before the true.

I have some ideas on how to accomplish this but what would be considered "idiomatic" in the new generics world? My application is performance sensitive.

---

Using a type union with types that all have the same function doesn't work (https://play.golang.com/p/QWE-XteWpjL).

Embedding a container inside type specific structs does work ( https://play.golang.com/p/j0AR48Mto-a ) but requires the use of an interface which means that the `Less` and `Val` in the example functions can't be inlined. It also might not work so nicely if there isn't a clean delineation between the subsets in the type union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW there is already a library for sorting

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#Sort

#### 1. You can create interface with generic, then type assert to that.

example:

```golang
type Lesser[T SupportedType] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}

type Vec[T SupportedType] []T

func (vec Vec[T]) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return any(vec[a]).(Lesser[T]).Less(vec[b])
}

func main() {
    vs := Vec[String]([]String{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"})
    vb := Vec[Bool]([]Bool{false, true})
    fmt.Println(vs.Less(3, 1))
    fmt.Println(vb.Less(0, 1))
}
```

[playground 1](https://go.dev/play/p/xrJhwcrmFX7)

#### 2. You can save the type on Vec.

example:

```golang
type Lesser[T SupportedType] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}

type Vec[T SupportedType, L Lesser[T]] []T

func (vec Vec[T, L]) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return any(vec[a]).(L).Less(vec[b])
}

func main() {
    vs := Vec[String, String]([]String{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"})
    fmt.Println(vs.Less(3, 1))
}
```

[playground 2](https://go.dev/play/p/xiraFq-Ycim)

#### 3. Nesting type constraint

thanks @blackgreen

example :

```golang
type SupportedType interface {
    Int8 | Time | Bool | String
}

type Lesser[T SupportedType] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}

type Vec[T interface {
    SupportedType
    Lesser[T]
}] []T

func (vec Vec[T]) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return vec[a].Less(vec[b])
}

func main() {
    vs := Vec[String]([]String{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"})
    fmt.Println(vs.Less(3, 1))
}
```

[playgrond 3](https://go.dev/play/p/niKaBH_xutx)

### Benchmark:

```golang
benchmark 1 : 28093368          36.52 ns/op       16 B/op          1 allocs/op

benchmark 2 : 164784321          7.231 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op

benchmark 3 : 212480662          5.733 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op

Embedding a container inside type specific structs:
benchmark 4 : 211429621          5.720 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

It's up to you which one is best for you. But IMO number 3 is best.

Comment: note that `any(vec[a]).(Lesser[T])` may panic because `T` can be instantiated with types that are in the union but do not implement `Lesser` https://go.dev/play/p/78dcLRSQd9p

Comment: yup, that's why this type constraint is named `SupportedType`

Comment: I know, my point is that it could be also called `Foobar` for that matter, so it’s better to use the compiler to ensure type safety as much as possible, instead of the developers doing the “right thing”

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it's best to not include in a union a lot of types that are unrelated to each other, as they wouldn't share many common operations, and you end up writing type-specific code. So then what's the point of using generics...?

Anyway, possible strategies depend on what is included in the type set of `SupportedType` constraint, and what you want to do with those:

**Only exact types and no methods**

Use a type switch on `T` and run whatever operation makes sense for the concrete type. This works best when the method implementation works with only one value of type `T`, as you can work directly with the variable in the switch guard (`v := any(vec[a]).(type)`). It stops being pretty when you have more `T` values beside the one in the switch guard, as you have to convert & assert all of them individually:

```
func (vec Vec[T]) Less(a, b int) bool {
    switch v := any(vec[a]).(type) {
    case int64:
        return v < any(vec[b]).(int64)

    case time.Time:
        return v.Before(any(vec[b]).(time.Time))

    // more cases...
    }
    return false
}
```

**With methods**

Parametrize the interface that contains the methods and constrain its `T` to the supported types. Then constrain `Vector`'s type parameter **to both**.
The advantage of this one is to make sure that `Vector` can't be instantiated with types on which you forgot to implement `Less(T) bool` and get rid of the type assertion, which otherwise, could panic at runtime.

```
type Lesser[T SupportedType] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}

type Vec[T interface { SupportedType; Lesser[T] }] []T

func (vec Vec[T]) Less(a, b int) bool {
    return vec[a].Less(vec[b])
}
```

**With methods and predeclared types**

Impossible. Consider the following:

```
type SupportedTypes interface {
    // exact predeclared types
    int | string
}

type Lesser[T SupportedTypes] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}
```

The constraint `Lesser` has an empty type set, because neither `int` nor `string` can have methods. So here you fall back to the "exact types and no methods" case.

**With approximate types (`~T`)**

Changing the constraints above into approximate types:

```
type SupportedTypes interface {
    // approximate types
    ~int | ~string
}

type Lesser[T SupportedTypes] interface {
    Less(T) bool
}
```

The type switch is not an option, since `case ~int:` isn't legal. And the presence of a method on the constraint prevents you from instantiating with the predeclared types:

```
Vector[MyInt8]{} // ok when MyInt8 implements Lesser
Vector[int8]     // doesn't compile, int8 can't implement Lesser
```

So the options I see then are:

- force client code to use defined types, which in many cases might be just fine
- reduce the scope of the constraint to types that support the same operations
- reflection (benchmark to see if the performance penalty is too much for you), but reflection can't actually find the underlying type, so you're left with some hacks using `reflect.Kind` or `CanConvert`.

This might improve and possibly trump other options when/if [this proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45380) comes through.